# Passing two std::array elements as function arguments in non sequence order

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, metaprogramming

I'm trying to figured out how to pass elements of two std::arrays as function arguments in mixed order. It's quite simple task if the order of arguments does not matter or it's sequential (when elements of one array should be passed right after elements of another array).

We can simply use fold expression like this

```
#include <array>

template <typename ...T>
void foo_impl(const T&... Args)
{
    // The function will recieve arguments like this
    //
    // foo_impl("one", "two", "three", 1, 2, 3); 
    //
}

template <size_t ...Indexes>
void foo(const std::index_sequence<Indexes...>&)
{
    std::array<const char*, 3> values = {"one", "two", "three"};
    std::array<int, 3> keys = {1, 2, 3};

    foo_impl((values[Indexes])..., (keys[Indexes])...);
}

int main()
{
    foo(std::make_index_sequence<3>{});

    return 0;    
}
```

[Here is an example](https://godbolt.org/z/oeGh9b)

In such case the function foo_impl will recieve arguments in this order- **("one", "two", "three", 1, 2, 3)**, but for me it's important to mix them in specific order.

I can't create third array and combine the arguments because they have different types and items the real arrays contains could be quite expensive to copy/move around.

Also I can't recombine the arguments at the foo_impl function level because their order important for logging system. Previuosly I used a lot of macroses for it. But now I would like to refactor this code and make it more modern and simplier to debug and understand.

I would like to know is it possible to mix those std::array elements (with fold expression or similiar meta programming technique) and passes like that **("one", 1, "two", 2, "three", 3)** before calling foo or foo_impl?

Thanks in advance for any help!

P.S. Sorry for my english I'm not native speaker.

Comment: It's a bad practice to pass independent arrays of objects that are clearly related by index. You should combine them in tuples if they only exists in local context or consider making a dedicated class.

Comment: @Rinat Veliakhmedov. thank you for you suggestion but sooner or later I will have to unpack them back and pass to lower level sub systems for which order, real type (not std::pair type of which the lower sub systems not aware of and not ready to) and amount of arguments are important. Of course I will try it but I guess it won't fit.

Comment: @Michał Kaczorowski. Thanks for reply! It's not so simple as in the example, this code is only for demonstration of the problem. but I agree with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might do

```
template <std::size_t ...Is>
void foo(const std::index_sequence<Is...>&)
{
    std::array<const char*, 3> values = {"one", "two", "three"};
    std::array<int, 3> keys = {1, 2, 3};

    foo_impl(std::get<Is%2>(std::tie(keys, values))[Is / 2]...);
}

int main()
{
    foo(std::make_index_sequence<6>{});
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8fea93d6c0f79139)

Answer (score 1):

Turn them into pairs before passing:

```
#include <array>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

template <typename ...T>
void foo_impl(T... Args)
{
   ((std::cout << std::forward<T>(Args).first << " "<<  std::forward<T>(Args).second << " "), ...);
    // prints "1 one 2 two 3 three"
}

template <std::size_t ...Indexes>
void foo(const std::index_sequence<Indexes...>&)
{
    std::array<const char*, 3> values = {"one", "two", "three"};
    std::array<int, 3> keys = {1, 2, 3};

    foo_impl(std::pair{keys[Indexes], values[Indexes]}...);
}

int main()
{
    foo(std::make_index_sequence<3>{});

    return 0;    
}
```